# How to check whether a file is in tar format?

Tags: archive, tar

I want to implement a check of a tar file.
I am not interested only to check the file extension, but I need surer way to check.
For example for zip format I could check some lead bytes. But what is the way for tar files?

Regards,
B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the magic bytes at offset 257. If they match "ustar" including the null terminator, the file is probably a tar.

See: http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html

```
/* tar Header Block, from POSIX 1003.1-1990.  */

/* POSIX header.  */

struct posix_header
{                              /* byte offset */
  char name[100];               /*   0 */
  char mode[8];                 /* 100 */
  char uid[8];                  /* 108 */
  char gid[8];                  /* 116 */
  char size[12];                /* 124 */
  char mtime[12];               /* 136 */
  char chksum[8];               /* 148 */
  char typeflag;                /* 156 */
  char linkname[100];           /* 157 */
  char magic[6];                /* 257 */
  char version[2];              /* 263 */
  char uname[32];               /* 265 */
  char gname[32];               /* 297 */
  char devmajor[8];             /* 329 */
  char devminor[8];             /* 337 */
  char prefix[155];             /* 345 */
                                /* 500 */
};

#define TMAGIC   "ustar"        /* ustar and a null */
#define TMAGLEN  6
```

Comment: This is not reliable and incidentally fails with archives produced by GNU tar which are created with the incorrect magic number "ustar " (no NUL byte) and version " \0". GNU tar can produce ustar archives, but for some reason they chose not to do so by default.

Comment: @FUZxxl Huh, that's weird. Any idea why they would do such a thing?

Comment: No idea. Seems like vendor lock-in to me. The manpage says “in the next version we are going to produce POSIX archives by default” since about a decade though. There is no good reason for what GNU tar is doing. After all, their own format is not any more powerful than the POSIX (pax) format and the latter is easy to extend.

Answer (score 3):

You can check file's header.
Here's the specification: http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html

Answer (score 2):

In shell you can use the file command

```
file AFile.tar
AFile.tar: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
```

Answer (score 0):

A C++ code that checks the first magic string in a file in order to determine if it is a tar file. If unfortunately "star" appears exactly on the 257 location in a non-TAR file, it will produce a false positive, which is very unlikely:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>
bool isTarFile(const std::string& filePath) {
    std::ifstream file(filePath, std::ios::binary);
    if (!file) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not open file: " + filePath);
    }

    constexpr char magic[] = "ustar";
    constexpr size_t magicLength = sizeof(magic) - 1;
    constexpr size_t bufferSize = sizeof(magic);
    char buffer[bufferSize];

    // Seek to the magic string location in the header
    file.seekg(257);

    if (!file) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not seek to position 257 of file: " + filePath);
    }

    // Read the magic number
    file.read(buffer, bufferSize);

    if (!file) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not read from file: " + filePath);
    }

    // Check the file signature
    return (std::strncmp(buffer, magic, magicLength) == 0);
}
```